# How to add ALL elements from one class to an array of another class

Tags: c++

```
class Airplane{
public:

    string airplaneName;
    string captainName;
    string copilotName;
    int passangerNumber;
    bool captain;
    bool copilot;

};

class Fleet{

public:

    string fleetName;
    Airplane airplaneFleet;
};
```

So I have to add all elements from Airplane (actually a couple of airplanes) to one fleet, how do I do that. I've tried different codes but I'not even close, if you have some solution please explain, thanks!

Comment: Use [`vector<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve] .   Without an example of what you want to achieve it's a little hard to understand.

Comment: @mare319 Elaborate what you mean by "add".

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, you can either have an array of some defined size, or a `vector` to which you can add elements at runtime.

```
Airplane airplanesInFleet[10];  // Fixed - 10 airplans

std::vector<Airplane> airplanesInFleet;  // Dynamic - use 'push_back' to add airplane
```